# Eclipse does not want to run

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently been given an error message when I was trying to run Eclipse.

The fault itself : An error has occurred. See the log file C:\Users.....metadata.log

First of all I have installed another version of eclipse in case it helps, but actually did not. They I figured out that I should delete the org.eclipse.core.resoursec but it did not also brought me to success.

I know that I can run it by -clean but it would be great to know what the problem actually is

Here is the log file

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-03 13:01:21.184
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (83).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.net.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 54 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(PreferenceManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.PreferenceManager.migrate(PreferenceManager.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 54 more

> > > > !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-03 13:01:21.233
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (83).
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2558)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2441)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: you know, eclipse does not have free will ;-) it's a computer program :-)

Comment: now, talking serious, check up what kind of java (distro) you're using and share with us so we can help you

Comment: adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522. Eclipse version 4.2 I suppose

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a classpath issue from that stacktrace - more specifically, it seems to be looking for jce.jar and it is not able to find it. Check your classpath for jre lib value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new workspace. To force the workspace window prompt you need to change the settings in \configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG to true

That will fix it is because your workspace meta data is corrupted.